# Skin detection and masking everything else other than the skin

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have a given algorithm that gives me a logic 2x2 of the image. I want to know how to retain the skin while masking everything else.

I have tried to use `img = cat(3, img, img, img)`. First using `double` then `uint8`. Also tried converting the binary to grayscale first before using `cat`.

```
ims1 = (im(:,:,1)>95) & (im(:,:,2)>40) & (im(:,:,3)>20);
ims2 = (im(:,:,1)-im(:,:,2)>15) | (im(:,:,1)-im(:,:,3)>15);
ims3 = (im(:,:,1)-im(:,:,2)>15) & (im(:,:,1)>im(:,:,3));
ims = ims1 & ims2 & ims3;
ims = double(ims);
rgbImage = cat(3, ims, ims, ims);
figure, imshow(rgbImage);
```

I wanted a just skin image, but all it does is show up in a black and white binary logic image.

This is the progression into what it is supposed to look like.

Original:
[image: Original]

Filtered:
[image: Filtered]

Final:
[image: Final]

Comment: Try using the mask to set the non-skin pixels of the image to 0 to make them black

Comment: Reusing what you have got so far... try: `rgbImage = uint8(double(im).*rgbImage)`